# maximum performance from integrated Intel (Sandy Bridge) video

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, video, x11, wayland

We are trying to get as much video performance out of a small all-in-one NUC-type PC which according to `lspci` has the following graphics adaptor:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 36)
```

we want to maximise the performance of Firefox when it is playing videos from Youtube, Netflix, Stan etc.;  i.e., minimise tearing and stutter and make the playback of videos as accurate as possible.
Our application takes over the box entirely so that although it is an Ubuntu base, we don't run any desktop at all;  we run our own application which is the only X client on the machine, and that application launches Firefox.

We've spent some time experimenting with the hardware acceleration settings of Firefox, running Firefox as a Wayland client (MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1), tweaking the Intel driver settings etc. and it runs pretty well.  It would be tedious to list all the settings we have made, as there are about 20 such.

What we cannot understand is that despite all the effort, our video performance is somewhat *lower* (in terms of accurately replaying Youtube 50 FPS videos without stutter) than the as-installed Firefox + Unity combination of a standard Ubuntu installation.  ***What could that combination be doing, that we have missed?***  The standard *prefs.js* file (available via `about:config`) does not use any of the supposedly performance-boosting settings that our own application does.  If we turn off our performance settings, our own app. is markedly *worse*, so our settings *are* helping, but it seems that the standard installation has some secret sauce.  What might it be?